# Entity framework condidional query building

Tags: c#, linq, projection, entity-framework-6.1

I have problem with creating complex query with entity framework. I would like to fetch additional data into my linq entity based on parameters given during construction of such query. Here is example with where:

```
        if (featureEnabled)
        {
            query = query.Where(n => *condition*);
        }
```

I have complex object created like that:

```
n => new Entity{
    Property = n.Something
    \* ... *\
    PropertyN = n.SomethingN,
}
```

and I want to load additional data into entity if feature is enabled (just like in where example):

```
public DoSomething(bool featureEnabled, feature2Enabled, etc.)
{
  return n => new Entity{
    Property = n.Something,
    \* ... *\
    PropertyN = n.SomethingN,
    Feature = (featureEnabled) ? *fetch some data from navigation property* : 0,
    Feature2 = (feature2Enabled) etc.
  }
}
```

In above example parameters (featureNEnabled) will be translated into sql parameters. How to perform such operation at query construction time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found answer to my question [on this blog](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/01/merging-expression-trees-to-reuse-in-linq-queries/)
With this code you may call expression.Merge(expression2) and initialization lists of two objects will be merged into one query.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean inside the `initializer` you want use the if condition?

if its so i will have its not possible.  To use the if condition you have to put it outside the initializer

```
var a = new MyClass{
prop1 = n.prop1,
prop2 = n.prop2,
prop3 = n.prop3,
};

a.propN = boolCondition ? n.PropN : 0;
```

Comment: Lambda expression with statement body cannot be converted into expression tree. I want to generate code in initializer based on configuration variables.

Comment: did you mention it in ur question you want that too??

Comment: Yes - "I would like to fetch additional data into my linq entity based on parameters given during construction of such query." Can you tell me what is unclear?

Comment: but as far as i understand - fetching the value don't have anything to do with tree..

Comment: My linq query is translated to expression tree and then to sql statement. Fetching the value will require additional join, calling stored proc, etc.

I want to cutoff tree branch in some cases without repeating code.